# How to effectively hide other fellow div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a drop down list and 5 divs along with it.I need to show one particular div at one time and hide the other.This is my approach
This is my code

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="tab-1">
        <br />
        <div id="one" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
        <div id="two" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
        <div id="three" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
        <div id="four" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
        <div id="five" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
        <div class="ui-select">
            <select name="usageDropDownList" id="usageDropDownList"
                data-native-menu="false" tabindex="-1">
                <option value="one">1</option>
                <option value="two">2</option>
                <option value="three">3</option>
                <option value="four">4</option>
                <option value="five">5</option>
            </select>
</div</div>
```

And here is my document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#usageDropDownList").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'one') {               
            $("#two").hide();
            $("#three").hide();
            $("#four").hide();
            $("#five").hide();              
            $("#one").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'two') {
            $("#one").hide();
            $("#three").hide();
            $("#four").hide();
            $("#five").hide();              
            $("#two").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'three') {
            $("#one").hide();
            $("#two").hide();
            $("#four").hide();
            $("#five").hide();              
            $("#three").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'four') {
            $("#one").hide();
            $("#two").hide();
            $("#three").hide();
            $("#five").hide();              
            $("#four").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == 'five') {
            $("#one").hide();
            $("#two").hide();
            $("#three").hide();
            $("#four").hide();              
            $("#five").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Can any one suggest me a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
$("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
```

A breakdown:

```
$("#" + $(this).val())  // selects div with id equal to value of selected option
.show()                 // shows it
.siblings()             // then selects all of the other divs next to it
.hide()                 // and hides them
```

**Update:**

Since there is also the `<div class="ui-select">` next to the "number" divs in your markup, that will also be hidden (which is undesirable). You can fix this in many ways, here are two:

1: Make that div not be a sibling by simply placing a wrapper div around the "numbers":

```
<div> <!-- added this -->
  <div id="one" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div id="two" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div id="three" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div id="four" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div id="five" style="width: device-width; height: 150px;"></div>
</div>
```

2: Exclude the `ui-select` div specifically:

```
$("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().not(".ui-select").hide();
```

Comment: Hi @Jon if i write your code then my dropdownlist also hides. i dont want that. I want the drop down list to be excluded. :)

Comment: Yep, using siblings() selects more than just the divs you want to hide.

Comment: @Jon your second approach isn't working yet. But your first approach is working :). Maybe because you are excluding a class after hiding the sibling divs...

Comment: @Coder_sLaY: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/WMHxv/). Perhaps your HTML is not exactly what you posted here? I 'm excluding first and then hiding...

Comment: @Jon I have given you the exact code what i am using. Although maybe i am using jquery mobile so it is not working.Cant say...

Answer (score 1):

Well, just as a matter of cleaning up your code:

```
$('#one, #two, #three, #four, #five').hide();
$('#'+$(this).val()).show();
```

**Edit**: Try this then:

```
​$('#tab-1 ​​​div').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('id').length != -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});​​​
$('#'+$(this).val()).show();
```

Comment: Nope this is also good.But i wanted less hardcoded values. More efficient...Although your Answer is better then my approach so +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code adding a div

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="tab-1">
        <br />
        <div id="selection">       
            <div id="one" style="width: device-width; height: 50px;">A</div>
            <div id="two" style="display:none; width: device-width; height:50px;">B</div>
            <div id="three" style="display:none; width: device-width; height: 50px;">C</div>
            <div id="four" style="display:none; width: device-width; height: 50px;">D</div>
            <div id="five" style="display:none; width: device-width; height: 50px;">E</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-select">
            <select name="usageDropDownList" id="usageDropDownList">
                <option value="one">1</option>
                <option value="two">2</option>
                <option value="three">3</option>
                <option value="four">4</option>
                <option value="five">5</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then your code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#usageDropDownList").change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $("#selection > div:visible").hide();
        $("#"+selected).show();
    });
});
```

You can try this code here  : http://jsfiddle.net/cRbUS/8/